# foreach javascript array

Tags: javascript, foreach

Possuo o seguinte script:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($lista_tipo_indicadores) ?>' );
  var cores = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($cores) ?>');
  // Quantidade de Indicadores por Tipo
  var doughnutData = [
      {
          value: data[0].total,
          color:cores[0],
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
         label: data[0].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[1].total,
          color: cores[1],
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: data[1].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[2].total,
          color: cores[2],
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: data[2].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[3].total,
          color: cores[3],
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: data[3].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[4].total,
          color: cores[4],
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: data[4].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[5].total,
          color: cores[5],
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: data[5].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[6].total,
          color: cores[6],
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: data[6].nome
      },
      {
          value: data[7].total,
          color: cores[7],
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: data[7].nome
      }
  ];
```

Como faço para que a variável  seja gerada de forma dinâmica, com algum foreach?

Comment: Confirme se eu entendi corretamente, você quer preencher a variável doughnutData por foreach em vez de ter de fazer manualmente?

Comment: Qual é a relação entre data e cores e highlight? As cores vêm da array cores imagino, mas têm ambas o mesmo numero de elementos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso ambas as arrays tenham o mesmo tamanho, ie `length` podes iterar uma delas e mapear para incluir dados da outra. Parece-me mais prático iterar `data` pois têm mais conteúdo a ser usado.

Assim podes fazer:

```
// Quantidade de Indicadores por Tipo
var doughnutData = data.map(function(_data, i){
      return {
          value: _data.total,
          color: cores[i],
          label: _data.nome
      };
});
```

Não está bem claro a relação com o `highlight` mas se isso fôr uma terceira array podes integrar da mesma maneira. Um exemplo usando highlight como ponto de partida seria:

```
var highlight = ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#FFC870"];
var doughnutData = highlight.map(function(_highlight, i){
      return {
          value: data[i].total,
          color: cores[i],
          highlight: _highlight
          label: data[i].nome
      };
});
```

Comment: Show de bola sua resposta sérgio. A ultima opção funcionou perfeitamente. :D